# How to solve these calculations faster?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$\frac{7}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{8}}{23}$ and .$\frac{\sqrt{45}}{\sqrt{7}}$ .I am preparing for JEE exam in which we cannot use calculators. So , I want to know how can I solve these questions faster ?. We have to solve each one them i.e by dividing. How can I do that faster

A healthy young man standing at a distance of 7m from a 11.8m high building see a kid slipping from the top floor. With speed (assumed uniform) should he run to catch the kid at the arms height (1.8m).
I got square root of 2 seconds as the time need for young man to go . Hence it is answer for 1st one
a) 4.7m/s
b)4.9m/s
c)7m/s
d) none of these

Comment: $7>\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{8} < 23$. For the general case, square both and compare the resulting fractions.

Comment: So like $\frac{7}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 4.9497$?

Comment: Are you trying to compare them?

Comment: No.@JoshuaWang .

Comment: What are you trying to solve for then?

Comment: @JoshuaWang  I got this equation from a physics question  and need its answer which is in decimals . That’s it

Comment: Do you have log tables?

Comment: No.Nothing@Henry

Comment: Try Newton's Method, the special case for approximating square roots is called Heron's Method.

Comment: @JoshuaWang I need to solve their answer like we do 250/5. So like in 5 or 10sec max

Comment: I don't know about the JEE, but in university, even in engineering, you will most probably not have to do these calculations by yourself. However, if you are given multiple-choice questions, you may be able to use arithmetic techniques to cross some options out.

Comment: I got options as 4.9m/s , 4.7m/s , 7m/s and none of these.@Saeed

Comment: For the1st one question only

Comment: Can you show us the whole question?

Comment: @JoshuaWang as you requested.

Comment: The child is falling at $50$km/h. I don't see a happy ending, even if the man arrives in time to catch him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $g=9.8 \frac{m}{s^2}$ , it will make your calculations much easier:

The kid falls $h=10m$ in $t$ seconds:
$$h = \frac12 gt^2 $$
$$10 = \frac12 9.8 t^2$$
$$t^2 = \frac{10}{4.9}$$
$$t = \sqrt{ \frac{10}{4.9}}$$
Now, it helps to see that 10 and 4.9 are just one tenth of 100 and 49, which are perfect squares!
$$t = \sqrt{ \frac{100}{49}} = \frac{10}{7}$$
The rest is easy for you: the man should run $x=7m$ in $t=\frac{10}{7}s$
$$v=\frac{x}{t} = \frac{7}{\frac{10}{7}}=4.9$$

Comment: $g=10$m/s$^2$ is what my friends did at uni. And they were physicists

Comment: Nice answer. I think this is what the person who made the question thought of.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this

Comment: @user102532 I have no idea why! Anyway, I can see that your approach was correct. You correctly figured out the distance of the fall, and you correctly identified the formula to calculate time. Only, you started with $g=10\frac{m}{s^2}$ which is usually a good assumption, but in this particular problem I feel it was the trick that the test maker had in mind. I think it is fair that in such exams, students are explicitly told what value to use for $g$. Also, the rest of your work was correct: trying to calculate speed as the ratio of distance to time.

Comment: @Saeed All the answers to this question got downvoted

Comment: @Forester Yes, that was strange. Btw thanks for the compliment. Your answer was nice too.